# Ember-cli import node package into test

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm, ember-cli

I need to include jwt-simple into a test so that I can generate JWT tokens and validate the UI does what it needs to do given certain scenarios.

I have tried `npm install jwt-simple` and then `import jwt from 'jwt-simple/jwt';` and `import jwt from 'jwt-simple';` but neither work.

Should I be able to import node packages into the tests like this?

Answer (score 0):

As `jwt-simple` is not an `ember` addon, you cannot import the module like this in an `ember-cli` setup. To import an npm module which is not an `ember` addon, you will need [ember-browserify](https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify). So install `ember-browserify` first:

```
npm install --save-dev ember-browserify
```

Then import the module as follows:

```
import jwt from 'npm:jwt-simple';
```